# MySQL not working after installing git

Tags: 16.04, mysql, git

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and everything was fine until I installed `git` on the server. Now apparently MySQL is stopped and it doesn't start.

---

Here is the result of `mysql -V`:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

---

And here is the result of `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`:

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!
```

---

An here is the result of `mysql -u root -p<myPassword>`

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Any idea how can I fix the problem?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the result of `systemctl status mysql.service` command:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-02-26 14:07:46 CET; 6s ago
  Process: 9641 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9634 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9641 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 9642 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─9642 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─9656 sleep 1

Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.416882Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.417028Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.639899Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.643617Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 9641 ...
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.646599Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Permission denied
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.647922Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.648209Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com mysqld[9641]: 2018-02-26T13:07:46.648540Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Feb 26 14:07:46 lamtakam.com systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you edit and add the output of this command ? `systemctl status mysql.service`

Comment: @Félicien I added the result of that command.

Comment: try to delete `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and try again

Comment: @Félicien I did https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1lfd.png. What's next ?

Comment: @Félicien and still the error is there https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8UzF.png

Comment: restart mysql first, `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: @Félicien The result of restarting mysql: `[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. failed!`

Comment: and `systemctl status mysql.service` didn't change ?

Comment: @Félicien https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/2d92d36bb4e24263174d0c50cd44dbcd

Comment: You still have the permission issue. Can you show us `ls -l /var/log/mysql`?

Comment: @Félicien https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/97463e242ad2c7e7800cf3caf898f292

Comment: What if you start mysql as mysql user ? `sudo -u mysql /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: @Félicien The same error. One thing, is it possible I give you my server user and pass and you do a favor and take a look at it?

Comment: @Félicien My problem resolved. Using this command: `sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql`

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Comment: On another note I recommend that you change the group owner of `/var/log/mysql` to `adm` like [its children](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/97463e242ad2c7e7800cf3caf898f292): `sudo chgrp adm /var/log/mysql`.

Comment: You might find [this useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user which you used to start mysql does not have enough permission to write  to file systems.
Porcess was unable to write to : /var/log/mysql/error.log

Ensure that you have write permission

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)